# Manipulating data from sqlite database

Tags: sqlite

Am a beginner in android development and i am designing an android app which takes input of a date and stores it in sqlite database. Could you please explain how i can retrieve the date and use it to calculate other dates which i will display in another activity
Eg if input is 1/1/2019, i need to calculate events that occur after this date and display them in order of events and the date
Event 1 - 12/01/2019
Event 2 - 2/02/2019
Event 3 -  26/02/2019

Event 1 occurs after like 21 days, event 2 occurs after like 24 days
How should i perform this calculation and display them in another activity?

Comment: Take a look at https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

The link mentioned above is correct. To put it simply just use SQLite's *date* function - it can calculate dates quite easily:

```sql
SELECT date('2019-01-12', '+21 days');
```

gives you `2019-02-02`.

Instead of the date value use a column name of your table if approbiate.

Take the calculated date for the second event and add 24 days and SQLite gives you the date for the third event.

```sql
SELECT date('2019-02-02', '+24 days');
```

`2019-02-26`

*Hint: my answer only deals with the database side (cause that's what your question is tagged with). I have no idea about the Android programming.*